# a convolutional equation for the gaussian measure

Tags: measure-theory

My question is: Let $\mu$ be the gaussian probability. Is there exists a measure $\nu$ solution of the equation:
$\nu*\mu=\delta$ where $\delta$ is the Dirac measure supported at the origin.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

No, by Bochner's Theorem the Fourier transform  of a measure is positive definite and hence bounded.

Answer (score 1):

A stronger statement is true. There are no probability measures $\mu,\nu$, other than $\delta$-measures which satisfy $\mu\star\nu=\delta$.